# Javascript Toggle on keydown

Tags: javascript, toggle, keydown

I'm pretty new when it comes to getting my head around JS functions. Everything I've used before, I've tended to use as-is, but I've been trying to combine and modify a function to get a Div to toggle (height & opacity) on a specific keypress. I have the first part (can get the div to show on a 'ctrl + o' combo), but can't combine it with an if statement to show or hide, based on current display status.

Current working 'show only' JS:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 79 && e.ctrlKey) {
        document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = 'auto';
        document.getElementById('thediv').style.opacity = '1';
        return false;
    }
});
```

Not working 'toggle on/off' JS (I've tried changing this all over the place; this is more to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve):

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76 && e.ctrlKey) {

        function toggler('thediv') {
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('thediv').style.height;
            if (myDiv == "auto") {
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = "0px";
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.opacity = "0";

            } else {
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = "auto";
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = "1";
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: you set height to auto doesn't mean that you will get height 'auto'

Comment: A demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) always helps.

Comment: Your `toggler()` function is never called. If you remove the line `function toggler('thediv') {` and its corresponding closing `}` then the code inside the function will actually run for that key combination. P.S. your second code block has `ctrl-L`, not `ctrl-O`...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both of you. Regarding the height 'auto', I suppose I just put it in and left it, as the opacity was working, so had no reason to change it.

Comment: nnnnnn, thanks for your advice. I tried removing that line, and it still didn't work, although this was probably due to my own error somewhere else. I managed to get it working using the toggle advice from epascarello. (Also, yes, I started with ctrl + l, must've copied from the wrong place :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show and hide an element, why set its height and visibility? Just show/hide it with [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76 && e.ctrlKey) {
         $("#thediv").toggle();
    }
});
```

Looking at your code

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76 && e.ctrlKey) {

        //This funciton is never called, you define it, do not call it!
        function toggler('thediv') { //<-- Error Here, you have a string as an argument?
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('thediv').style.height;
            if (myDiv == "auto") {
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = "0px";  //<--Bad practice using document.getElementById('thediv') over and over. Store it into a variable and reference it.
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.opacity = "0";

            } else {
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = "auto";
                document.getElementById('thediv').style.height = "1";
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback epascarello! I was using the height and opacity, so I could use CSS transitions (I read that using display could break them, but I see that toggle can do transitions too).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks epascarello. I got it working using toggle, and managed to get the same fade in.'


    `$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 79 && e.ctrlKey) {
    $("#thediv").fadeToggle('fast');
    }
    });`